# Powershell to get value using XPath and convert into comma separated string

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath, command-line, xml-parsing

```
<data>
    <ValueSet Version="6.6">
        <entry key="ORGID">
            <Value>852357951364</Value>
        </entry>
        <entry key="MESSAGE_CODE">
            <Value>MESSAGE1</Value>
        </entry>
        <entry key="REVERSAL">
            <Value>REVERSAL1</Value>
        </entry>
    </ValueSet>
    <ValueSet Version="6.6">
        <entry key="ORGID">
            <Value>852357951365</Value>
        </entry>
        <entry key="MESSAGE_CODE">
            <Value>MESSAGE2</Value>
        </entry>
        <entry key="REVERSAL">
            <Value>REVERSAL2</Value>
        </entry>
    </ValueSet>
</data>
```

I have taken ORGID value alone from above XML using below Powershell Script

```
$XMLfile = 'C:\Users\XML_Input.xml'
Select-Xml -Path $XMLfile -XPath '//entry[@key="ORGID"]' | foreach {$_.node.Value}
```

.

Post execution of above PowerShell script, the ORGID is printing one by one like below
.
**852357951364**

**852357951365**

Instead of printing ORGID one by one, I want to print ORGID in a comma separated value in single line like **852357951364,852357951365**

Please help me to form an output with single line string

Comment: Use `-join` operator  `(Select-Xml -Path $XMLfile -XPath '//entry[@key="ORGID"]' | foreach {$_.node.Value}) -join ","`

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't specific to XML parsing. It can be reduced to:

- Given a PowerShell pipeline that outputs a variable number of objects, how can I join these (as strings) with a separator to form a single string?

You have two options:

- `-join`, the [string joining operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Join).
- Alternatively, in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), you can use the [`Join-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/join-string?view=powershell-7.3&WT.mc_id=ps-gethelp) cmdlet, which offers many more features.

Applied to your case:

```bash
# -join operator
(Select-Xml -Path $XMLfile -XPath '//entry[@key="ORGID"]').Node.Value -join ','

# PS v7+: Join-String cmdlet.
(Select-Xml -Path $XMLfile -XPath '//entry[@key="ORGID"]').Node |
  Join-String -Property Value -Separator ','
```

Note:

- Both commands take advantage of [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration), which allows you to access a property directly on an *array* (list-like data type) and have PowerShell automatically apply it to *each element*, returning the results as an *array of values* (assuming there are two or more).
- With `-join`, *two* levels of member-access enumerations are applied (`.Node.Value`), making the use of `foreach {$_.node.Value}` unnecessary.
- With `Join-String`, I've only used one level (`.Node`), so as to showcase `Join-String`'s ability to accept a target property name via `-Property`.

  - However, note that not using member-access enumeration and trying `-Property Node.Value` would *not* work, because `Node.Value` would then be interpreted as a *single* property name literally named `Node.Value`; the same caveat applies to all cmdlets that have `-Property` parameters, such as [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object).

Answer (score 0):

Using Powershell

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$inputFilename = "c:\temp\test.xml"
$outputFilename = "c:\temp\test.csv"

$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($inputFilename)
$valueSets = $doc.Descendants("ValueSet")

$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
foreach($valueSet in $valueSets)
{
   foreach($entry in $valueset.Elements())
   {
      $key = $entry.Attribute('key').Value
      $value = $entry.Descendants('Value')[0].Value

      switch($key)
      {
         'ORGID' {$orgid = $value}
         'MESSAGE_CODE' {$messageCode = $value}
         'REVERSAL' {$reversal = $value}
      }
   }
   $newRow = [pscustomobject]@{
         ORGID=$orgid
         MESSAGE_CODE=$messageCode
         REVERSAL=$reversal
   }
   $table.Add($newRow) | Out-Null
}
$table | Format-Table
$table | Export-CSV -Path $outputFilename -NoTypeInformation
```

Results

```
"ORGID","MESSAGE_CODE","REVERSAL"
"852357951364","MESSAGE1","REVERSAL1"
"852357951365","MESSAGE2","REVERSAL2"
```